# Selenium WebDriver connection refused in .NET Core app, using .NET Framework class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, asp.net-core, remotewebdriver

In `.NET Core`, Selenium isn't supported yet, making it tough to do front end web tests. Fortunately, you're able to reference the packages if you add a separate project to your solution that is a `C# Class Library` pointed at `.NET Framework`.

I've done just this, but I'm receiving connection errors from the Selenium web driver that state `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:4444` which tells me the server is hit and responds without timing out, but is refused for some reason.

Here is the **error** I receive

```
{"Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:4444 
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary'2 parameters)"}
```

And here is the full **stack trace**

```
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at JabbR_Core.WebTests.LobbyTests.LoadAndWait() in C:\Users\jaearle\Documents\Code\JabbR-Core\test\JabbR-Core.WebTests\LobbyTests.cs:line 15
```

Here is my **testing class**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Project.WebTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Tests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void LoadAndWait()
        {
            IWebDriver wd = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:59395/"), DesiredCapabilities.Chrome());
            try
            {
                wd.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:59395/");

                Thread.Sleep(5000);

                if (!(wd.FindElements(By.CssSelector("section#page")).Count != 0))
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("verifyElementPresent failed");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                wd.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you're running remote `Selenium Server`, it runs on default address which is `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub` on local machine. I think you're point incorrect remote address during initialising of [`RemoteWebDriver`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver__ctor_2.htm). You should try as :-

```
IWebDriver wd = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"),DesiredCapabilities.Chrome());
```

Comment: This was the default that I tried to use before (127.0.0.1:4444, not the /wd/hub part though) and I changed it to match the localhost port the application normally runs on because I thought that may have been a fix. It didn't work before the change either, but I'll try adding /wd/hub to the URI